# What is the shortest non-interactive command to type in a prompt, on a fresh Windows 10, that downloads the latest Firefox installer?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, firefox, file-download

I'd like to install latest stable Firefox for Windows without having to open IE, Edge, or navigate through a FTP, or a text browser.

I'm looking for an easy to remember single command or one-liner that just downloads the right installer(best effort), w/o asking me questions, with the least amount of typing done on the command prompt(or the Run Command applet, or others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
curl -Lo Firefox.exe is.gd/FireFoxDL

rem :: Or, one line output ::
curl -#Lo Firefox.exe is.gd/FireFoxDL
```

---

```
# => Onle line progress bar
-L => deal with redirection/location
-o C:\folder\File.ext => Path to save your File.extension Output

rem :: Also work ::
curl is.gd/FireFoxDL -#Lo Firefox.exe
```

---

You can use the `curl` and short link:

**...[Windows 10 Insider build 17063 and later now include the real-deal curl and tar executables that you can execute directly from Cmd or PowerShell.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/)**

---

**1.** Acess *is good* => **[is.gd](http://is.gd)**

[image]

**2.** Click in custom:

[image]

**3.** Note if the string has already been used, I tested Firefox, FireFox and Mozilla strings, they were already in use, so I used FireFoxDL, FireFox DownLoad) but you can use any string that is easy to remember, name of people, places, dates, whatever what matters is not to forget.

[image]

**Obs.:1** This site also provides a QR of the sort link generated

[image]

**Obs.:2** Is the same service used by IOs in System/iDevices

Comment: It's great to know that curl comes with W10 since 2018, great find! I'm bit worried about privacy and security issues when using URL shorteners, but unless Mozilla themselves publish one, that's what we have. On the other hand, their installers are signed, and Windows displays who is the author.

Comment: I did end setting up a redirect in my own .dev domain. Sec issues solved.

Comment: @BrunoLaturner Very good your idea!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this command in Powershell:

```
iwr -Uri 'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win64&lang=en-US' -OutFile '.\FirefoxInstaller.exe'
```

Or in Powershell <=2.0:

```
(New-Object System.net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win64&lang=en-US', '.\FirefoxInstaller.exe')
```

This will Download latest firefox installer (currently v79) as FirefoxInstaller.exe in current directory, You can change using `cd` command before downloading.

*Note: `iwr` does show a progress meter on top of window, but `DownloadFile` method is absolutely silent, so choose the second if you need ultimate silence, unless there are errors.*

Or to be executed from cmd.exe or Run... box:

```
powershell -noProfile -command "& {(New-Object System.net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win64&lang=en-US', '.\FirefoxInstaller.exe')}"
```

Comment: I like the answer, providing a built-in downloader tool, however it's on the verbose side.